# Keeping 'current-menu-item' highlight of navigation menu?

Tags: menus

The navigation menu of my site is generated via

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary') );
```

Some menu entries are category pages (say `/category/news/`). This page contains links to the next level, single post posts (say `/news/123/`).

I noticed that the menu is only highlighted ('current-menu-item' class) when the category page is the current. How can I make the menu stay highlighted when viewing single post pages (`/news/123/`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `.current-menu-parent` class in your CSS to keep the category highlighted when viewing single posts.